# Binary Data Type in H2, Sql-Server, MySql

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, h2, hsqldb

I need to store a serialized `Object` as binary data in a H2 table (also in MySql, SqlServer, Hsqldb, etc, as the app have options to select the database). This object only weights few bytes, it is just a POJO with some Strings, Integers and Boolean values, nothing extraordinary.

I create the `VARBINARY(1000)` column set the value with a `PreparedStatement` and save it to the table. My question and my concern is that, this code works in a website and as I read the definition in the `H2` official site about the `BINARY` data type, there they say:

> **BINARY Type:**
>   Represents a byte array. For very long arrays, use BLOB. The maximum
>   size is 2 GB, *but the whole object is kept in memory when using this
>   data type*. The precision is a size constraint; only the actual data is
>   persisted. For large text data BLOB or CLOB should be used.

What worries me is that statement where they say "*but the whole object is kept in memory when using this data type*". So, how much time actually is this object hold in memory? Until application shutdown?

What I don't (obviously) want is to have this column eating the memory by keeping this column endlessly. I tried to find any other source of information but no luck whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best data type for HSQLDB and MySQL is `VARRBINARY(max_bytes_length)`. `BINARY(fixed_bytes_length)` takes the same amount of space even for the smallest saved object, while `VARBINARY` takes exactly the length of the saved object. The max_length parameter can be set to a value that is much larger than the maximum anticipated size of the object. Withe these databases, the value is held in memory only when the row of data is accessed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One last question: for data type `VARBINARY(max_length)`, what is the measurement of the `max_length` variable? Is it measured in `bytes`, `kilobytes`, `bits` (I don't think `bits` but just in case)?

Comment: OK, good. Thank you. In the respective documentations, they mention some information about the `VARBINARY ` and `BINARY` but they don't mention the unit of measurement, very important though. They may think it is already understood, but terrible mistake, a documentation must always keep a *complete* description of the object trying to describe.

Answer (score 0):

The `BLOB` type won't be kept fully in memory, so if you are concerned about memory usage you could use that. How much data are you storing anyway?

H2 is an embedded database, I don't think its intended to scale to large amounts of data. If you are talking about the other databases, you should refer to their documentation for details as they are unlikely to behave the same way.

Comment: As I understand `BLOB` data type is for columns beyond the 2GB and as I said, the data only weights few bytes because it is only the serialization of a POJO.

Comment: when you say also in mysql, etc. are you just using `h2` for testing?

Comment: No, the app let the final user to select the final database to use, so I test the same code for all MySql and Sql-Server as well. I only need to store a small amount of bytes but not to keep it in memory as the H2 documentation says. This is why I think `BLOB` is like using a canyon for a fly.